# How to read an xsd:dateTime with msxml?

Tags: c++, xml, datetime, msxml

I'm using the msxml to parse an xml file. Language is C++. The xml file contains some dates and times using the xsd:dateTime format (Something like that: 2009-04-29T12:00:00Z)

Is there an easy way to convert xsd:dateTime to something like SYSTEMTIME, FILETIME or VariantTime?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps you: [Using strptime to parse ISO 8601 formated timestamps](http://www.ioncannon.net/cc/33/using-strptime-to-parse-iso-8601-formated-timestamps/) on ioncannon.net.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. strptime is a quite interesting function, but it is not available on Windows... I saw on the internet some implementations of strptime under bsd licence, but I think it would need quite work until it compiles on Windows...

Comment: It was just a shot in the dark, really. I'm sorry. :-\

Comment: It is still a good answer. It might help someone looking for the same thing on unix. And it gives me new search directions to find a solution on windows.

Comment: I hope someone from the C++ front can help you. Setting a bounty to this question when no answers come in may help to draw attention to it (bonties are enabled a few days after posting the question).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a javascript:

```
<xsl:transform
id="integra-transformer"
version="1.0"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:date="urn:date-scripts">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<msxsl:script 
    implements-prefix="date" 
    language="javascript">
    <![CDATA[
    Date.prototype.toISO8601ShortString = function () {
        var zeropad = function (num) { return ((num < 10) ? '0' : '') + num;  }
        var str = "";
        var date = new Date();
        str += date.getUTCFullYear();
        str += "-" + zeropad(date.getUTCMonth() + 1);
        str += "-" + zeropad(date.getUTCDate());
        str += "T" + zeropad(date.getUTCHours()) +
        ":" + zeropad(date.getUTCMinutes());
        return str;
    }

    function getToday()
    {
        var d;
        d = new Date();
        return(d.toISO8601ShortString());
    }
    ]]>
</msxsl:script>


<xsl:template match="/">
         <date>
             <xsl:value-of select="date:getToday()"/>
         </date>
     </xsl:template>
 </xsl:transform>
```

Don't forget to enable scripts befor you do the transformation:

```
xslDom.setProperty("AllowXsltScript", true)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as far as I understand your script is to convert a date to xsd:dateTime and not from xsd:dateTime. The problem in converting "from xsd:dateTime" is that xsd:dateTime allows a lot of different syntaxes (for example a week number instead of a date, ...)